# Micro focus Content Manager CMServiceAPI POST error

Tags: trim

I am testing the Micro focus Content Manager 23.4 in the dev environment using CMServiceAPI , all the GET functions work fine, however all the POST function get 403 error: Could not deserialize request.

eg. Delete a record:

curl -X POST --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --header 'Accept: application/json' -d 'DeleteRecordDeleteContents=true' 'http://servername/CMServiceAPI/Record/1/Delete'

checking the server log, see this error:
2024-02-20 18:19:07,861 [40] ERROR HP.HPTRIM.Service.TrimAppHost - The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L0NNU2VydmljZUFQSQ2" is not present.
ServiceStack.HttpError: The required anti-forgery cookie "__RequestVerificationToken_L0NNU2VydmljZUFQSQ2" is not present.
at HP.HPTRIM.Service.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken.Execute(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto)
at HP.HPTRIM.Service.ValidateHttpAntiForgeryToken.RequestFilter(IRequest req, IResponse res, Object requestDto)
at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.d__435.MoveNext() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.Runtime.cs:line 230
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at ServiceStack.ServiceStackHost.d__434.MoveNext() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/ServiceStackHost.Runtime.cs:line 144
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
at ServiceStack.Host.RestHandler.d__14.MoveNext() in /home/runner/work/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Host/RestHandler.cs:line 93

BTW, create record, delete record works fine in Content Manager GUI.

Did I miss anything in CMServiceAPI configuration?

Any suggestions really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

The error is the Anti Forgery token was not present in your CURL requests, whereas they would be sent in your UI.